# call different variables with the same prefix changing only suffix

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

I have 20 variables (it may be 20 different mutableList items, or it may be a 20 buttons or any other objects), for example:

```
var ex1 
var ex2 
var ex3 
...
var ex20
```

And i need to make a `for` loop, which will look like this:

```
for (i in 0 until 20) {
//here i want to do something with variable that i have declared earlier
i+1
}
```

so, how can i go throught all the variables?

Comment: use an array...

Comment: edited my post to clarify what i am considering under "variables"

Comment: *20 different mutableList items, or it may be a 20 buttons* can be stored in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array var[] ex and insert all the twenty var elements to that array. Iterate the array inside the for loop to access the 20 var elements

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible, you should really take a look into using arrays for this kind of behavior.

```
val array = arrayOf(5, 32, 555, 921)

//To get numbers in array
for(num in array) {
    //Do something
}

//To change numbers in array
for(i in 0 until array.size) {
    array[i] = 2
}
```

Comment: Maybe change it to `0 until array.size`?

Comment: Changed the answer as @forpas pointed out. Using 0..array.size would result in a crash.

Comment: edited my post to clarify what i am considering under "variables"

Comment: You still have 20 mutableLists or 20 buttons, why not to put them into an array or list? I could come up with a dirty solution using enum, but I would never recommend you to use it. (Let me know if you still want to see it.) You probably want to put your variables into an array or a list.

Comment: Or you could quite possible use reflection to achieve this, but dont do it as it would be a bad practice in your case.